Why does the diametric form of a circle represent only one circle?
As per my understanding, the diametric form of a circle,
$(x-x_1)(x-x_2)+(y-y_1)(y-y_2)=0$
represents a circle passing through the points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$, with the line joining those points as its diameter. However, my confusion lies in the fact that wouldn't this equation represent an infinite number of that pass through those points, therefore representing a family of circles?

There can be only one line segment, passing through the two points. If the points are end points of a diameter, how can there be a family of circles? The two points can only represent only a single diameter and hence a single circle.

@M.Riyan I understand that, but why is it that the line joining those points is the diameter of the circle in the first place?

The equation creates such a circle that considers the two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ as the end points of the diameter. Then, should the straight line joining these two points be the diameter of the circle?

Here is one possible approach.
Let $x_1=a,y_1=b,x_2=c,y_2=d$ so the equation becomes $(x-a)(x-c)+(y-b)(y-d)=0$.
Expanding and collecting like terms gives $x^2-(a+c)x+ac+y^2-(b+d)y+bd=0$
This is the equation of a circle with centre $(\frac{a+c}{2},\frac{b+d}{2})$.
The equation can then be re-written $(x-\frac{a+c}{2})^2+(y-\frac{b+d}{2})^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+ac+bd$
There is one centre and one radius, therefore the circle is unique.
Edit
As to why the line segment joining $(a,c)$ to $(b,d)$ is the diameter, it is easy enough to show that the midpoint of the line segment and the centre of the circle found above are the same point.
It is also easy enough to show that the square of the distance between the two points is four times the square of the radius, thus the distance is twice the radius - by definition a segment through the centre of a circle with length $2r$ is a diameter.
